# how to prevent authorization header in browser network tab

Tags: angular, authorization, angular5

**Angular 5** **Authorization** header are **shown** in **browser** **network** tab.

[image: description]

**How** to **prevent** this **Authorization** header?

Comment: You can't prevent IMO.

Answer (score 3):

You can't. [ANY HTTP headers by default](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers) will be seen in the browser, at any time:

> **End-to-end headers:** These headers must be transmitted to the final
>   recipient of the message; that is, the server for a request or the
>   client for a response. Intermediate proxies must retransmit end-to-end
>   headers unmodified and caches must store them.

To make your application secure, use HTTPS, and if you really do not want to show which header is the authentication, replace it with a custom header. Also, if you really need to hide the data inside it, encrypt the token with a custom logic.